# Science stack exchanges helping other science stack exchanges!

Tags: discussion

The Physics Meta promotes support for all Science sites on Stack Exchange, in [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) post. The same meta post is now on several other science SE Meta sites.

The Engineering SE is one of the sites that has benefited from this (and is currently still benefiting from this, if you look at the "Sites in Beta" section of that Meta post).

Let's give back to the younger science communities, now that we here at Engineering have graduated out of the Commitment stage, and let's help some of the other sites in Beta, as they are doing for us.

Below is the post from the Physics Meta (now on several others too).

Comment: Are you even sure that Area51 is even still functioning? My impression was that it was all but dead.

Comment: @hazzey: Have you looked at Area51 lately? The Materials Design proposal is 20 commitments from going to Beta, and several new proposals were launched over the last few days.

Comment: I was basing my comments about Area51 from this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344244/282289

Comment: @hazzey: In that answer, and his reply to my comment on it, he is saying that the company is still not sure whether or not they will end A51. For now it is still running, and since traffic at A51 has dropped extremely ever since they shut down 99% of the proposals due to the new 4-month limit to finish commitment phase (which is quite extreme), new proposals need people's help more than ever. My guess is that Materials might be the last site to get launched before they shut down A51. Since it was proposed well before they fired Robert Cartaino and Shog09, they seem to be letting it through.

Comment: In any case, Engineering and other sites still need support and more users, to graduate from Beta into a full-fledged site, so even if A51 shuts down, it's good to continue advertising Engineering to other SE's, and reciprocating in the same way for them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Science proposals need your help! Consider committing to these, to make them successful & scientific:

See also the long list of [science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=progress) and [technology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=progress) proposals on Area 51.

---

## Committers needed

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Synthetic Biology]

---

## Site definition needed

---

## Sites in beta

[Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=beta) and [technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=beta) sites currently in beta include:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Materials Modeling]
[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Operations Research]
[image: Astronomy]
[image: Earth Science]
[image: Engineering]
[image: Mathematics Educators]
[image: Open Data]
[image]

---

This is community wiki -- feel free to add other proposals worth mentioning.

Comment: Removed HSM because of [this](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/325/8052) (you will need enough rep to see it though, since it's deleted).